# Java annotation processor, annotation types with annotations

Tags: java, compilation, annotations

I am using a annotation processor to process annotations of method parameters.

```
public void multiply(@IntArg int a){
    ...
}
```

The annotations types used for the parameters have an annotation, @Argument

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Argument
public @interface IntArg {
}
```

Now, when my annotation processor is running, I want to check if a parameter annotation (`@IntArg`) has the `@Argument` annotation. I do this by executing the following code.

```
VariableElement param = ... //The parameter
for (AnnotationMirror mirror : param.getAnnotationMirrors()) {
    Argument arg = mirror.getAnnotationType().getAnnotation(Argument.class);
    if(arg != null) {//Args is always null
        ...
    }
}
```

For some reason `arg` is always null. Is there a reason why the annotation is not returned?

Comment: Well, your parameter does not have `@Argument` annotation, so `arg` will be always `null`...

Comment: I am not getting the `@Argument` annotation of the parameter, I'm getting the annotation of the AnnotationType, which is IntArg in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
VariableElement param = ...;
for (AnnotationMirror mirror : param.getAnnotationMirrors()) {
    DeclaredType t = mirror.getAnnotationType();
    // (Filter out ErrorType: see my addendum.)
    if (t.getKind() == TypeKind.DECLARED) {
        Element e = t.asElement();
        // (This should always be true.)
        if (e.getKind() == ElementKind.ANNOTATION_TYPE) {
            Argument a = e.getAnnotation(Argument.class);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

From [`DeclaredType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html) and [`TypeElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html):

> While a `TypeElement` represents a class or interface *element*, a DeclaredType represents a class or interface *type*, the latter being a use (or *invocation*) of the former.

So if you want to examine a declaration somehow, you want the element rather than the type.

Note that I also could have casted `e` to a `TypeElement` in the above snippet; there was just no particular reason to.

---

Quick addendum regarding my edit: I think it's probably correct to check the [`TypeKind`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeKind.html) here because it's possible for `getAnnotationType()` to return an [`ErrorType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/ErrorType.html). This could happen if I did something like this:

```
void m(@IntArg @TypeWhichDoesntExist int arg0) {
}
```

Where `TypeWhichDoesntExist` is a type which doesn't exist, for example because it's not imported, because it's an `@interface` which is generated by another annotation processor or because it's altogether a non-existent type. (Annotation processors may be invoked with code that doesn't compile.)

I don't think this would have caused a problem with the way my example was written before, but I think it's worthwhile to point out that this could happen.